# Can you wield the power of the dark side and not be tempted by it?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

In other words, can one use dark side powers without feeling its temptation, without drowning in one's emotions, without falling into the darkness?

Comment: Not even vaguely a SW expert or even enthusiast here, but I do recall that in some canon there were with in the past who lead honorable lives, had loads of kids, lead good lives. In other words, being Sith was just another was of controlling power but didn't necessarily mean being evil. Since Sith base their power on dark side powers, this would seem to equate.

Comment: @Broklynite http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/15678/31051 Not canon anymore, though, since the Great Disneyfication

Comment: @thegreatjedi You mean like when Luke used the Force to choke a Gamorean guard at Jabba's palace? That's the only time (IIRC) that a light side force wielder used a dark side power like Force Choke.

Comment: @RichS wait, didn't I read recently that Leia tapped into the dark side in order to strangle Jabba?

Comment: In *Hallows* chapter 35, Professor Dumbledore suggests that it's possible, but takes an extraordinary character of ‘maybe a man in a million’ like Harry.  Professor Slughorn also seems to think most people are tempted: in *Prince* chapter 23, he says to Riddle: ‘It's natural to feel some curiosity about these things … wizards of a certain calibre have always been drawn to that aspect of magic …’

Answer (score 9):

### Without *temptation*, no; without *falling*, yes

This is something Ventress discusses with Quinlan Vos in the canon novel *Dark Disciple*; it's one of the Nightsister teachings, and something that she tries to teach him (emphasis mine):

> Ventress informed him that she would train him as a Nightsister would be trained. "I had conversations with Karis and Naa'leth. They told me of what they underwent. Nightsisters know the dark side better than anyone. We grow up steeped in it, but **we can use it as a tool and stay ourselves — unlike the Sith**. That balance is what you must learn."
>
> <sup>*Dark Disciple* Chapter 14</sup>

Despite being possible, it's evidently not easy, as Ventress admits later (emphasis mine):

> "The Jedi have always taught that the dark side is a quick and easy path."
>
> "You must be cautious how far down that quick and easy path you go," she warned. "Now that you have tapped into it, it can consume you. **It is a delicate balance to strike — being free enough to feed from it, but remaining your own master**."
>
> "Like you did."
>
> "**I fought my way back. I almost didn’t make it**."
>
> <sup>*Dark Disciple* Chapter 17</sup>

Comment: It could be noted that Luke Skywalker used The Force to choke a guard in Jabba's palace, which is a technique used by Dark Siders, and Mace Windu's fighting style borders and taps into the Dark Side, close enough to be dangerous to the user, but some Jedi (Mace Windu) were able to use it without falling.

Comment: @Petersaber More discussion on Luke and his Force choke: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/108353/31051. I recall that fact about Vaapad from Legends sources, but I don't believe it's canon any longer

Comment: non-Legends Form VII Wookiepedia page mentions Dark Side multiple times, and all sources are Disney-approved from what I know

Comment: @Petersaber Link? [This](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Form_VII) is the Canon page for Form VII, and no mention of the Dark Side is to be found, only that it's an aggressive style

Comment: @JasonBaker - it is Disney canon iirc. It's covered in ROTJ novelization when Windu fights Palpatine. Not in as great detail as in *Shatterpoint*, admittedly

Comment: @DVK-in-Florida Typical; it *would* be in the only novelization I didn't check. Thanks for the confirm

Comment: @JasonBaker - `Mace Windu had almost smiled. “I created Vaapad to answer my weakness: it channels my own darkness into a weapon of the light.` ...

Comment: @JasonBaker - `Vaapad, the seventh form of lightsaber combat, takes its name from a notoriously dangerous predator native to the moons of Sarapin: a vaapad attacks its prey with whipping strikes of its blindingly fast tentacles. Most have at least seven. It is not uncommon for them to have as many as twelve; the largest ever killed had twenty-three. With a vaapad, one never knew how many tentacles it had until it was dead: they move too fast to count. Almost too fast to see`

Comment: @JasonBaker - `Vaapad is as aggressive and powerful as its namesake, but its power comes at great risk: immersion in Vaapad opens the gates that restrain one’s inner darkness. To use Vaapad, a Jedi must allow himself to enjoy the fight; he must give himself over to the thrill of battle. The rush of winning. Vaapad is a path that leads through the penumbra of the dark side.`